# How to properly produce the corresponding SQL

Tags: mysql

Salutations, I am having trouble formulating the correct SQL query for the following request:

For each department, list number of employees born in each decade and their average salaries

Now, I figured I would need salaries, since we need an avg of salaries, 
along with a department name and a number of people born in a certain date that this should suffice in terms of the select values.

However, I am getting the following error:

`ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'employees.d.dept_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

This is my attempted SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.dept_name, AVG(s.salary), COUNT(e.birth_date)
        FROM employees e, departments d, salaries s, dept_emp de
        WHERE de.emp_no = e.emp_no
        AND de.dept_no = d.dept_no
        GROUP BY ROUND(YEAR(e.birth_date), -1);
```

I am brand new to SQL, so this is somewhat challenging for me as the professor has not explained how to properly generate SQL syntax appropriately.

The table description is as follows:

describe employees;

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| birth_date | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(14)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(16)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gender     | enum('M','F') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hire_date  | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

describe salaries;

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| salary    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| from_date | date    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| to_date   | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

describe departments;

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dept_no   | char(4)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dept_name | varchar(40) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and finally, describe dept_emp

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dept_no   | char(4) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| from_date | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| to_date   | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

How would a correct version of my query look like?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.dept_name, AVG(s.salary), ROUND(YEAR(e.birth_date), -1)
FROM employees e, departments d, salaries s, dept_emp de
WHERE de.emp_no = e.emp_no
AND de.dept_no = d.dept_no
AND e.emp_no = s.emp_no
GROUP BY d.dept_name, ROUND(YEAR(e.birth_date), -1);
```

Seems to at least produce an out that is validish.